# Unable to use extension method in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to display images from the local storage(not Content folder). The image tag I am using looks like this.

```
@if (Model.PreviousCoverPic != null)
{
    <img src="@Url.Action("ServeImage", "Profile",new {path = Model.PreviousCoverPic})" alt="Previous Profile Pic" />
}
```

I made the *ServerImage* method an extension method since it will be used by more than one controller. Here is the code for the method:

```
public static ActionResult ServeImage(this System.Web.Mvc.Controller controller, string path)
{
    Stream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    FileResult fileResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpg");
    return fileResult;
}
```

It returns a FileResult of the image so that it can be displayed. However, when the view is rendered it doesn't show the image. I checked the *Model.PreviousCoverPic* value and it is not null. What am I missing here? How can I achieve displaying methods from a local folder? Also, I followed the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115834/how-do-i-use-an-extension-method-in-an-asp-net-mvc-view?lq=1) question and added the name space of the class which contains the extension method but the image still doesn't get rendered in the view.

Comment: Did you include in your cshtml the namespace where the extension method is defined?

Comment: I included the namespace in the Web.config file so that it is included for all cshtml files.

Comment: I don't think it will work like that. Include it in your cshtml and let me know how that works

Comment: I also added it in the cshtml file with @using WebProj.Extensions.Controller but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following sources

[Can MVC action method be static or extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33496609/can-mvc-action-method-be-static-or-extension-method)

And this answer

[extend ASP.NET MVC action method,How to do return View](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514189/5233410)

The extension method wont work with routing the `Url.Action`. You can use inheritance to make a base class with the action. that way all inherited classes will have the action and calls to `Url.Action` will be valid.

```
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller {
    public ActionResult ServeImage(string path) {...}
}

public class ConcreteController : MyBaseController {...}
```

Comment: Thanks, I works that way. I thought using extension methods would be cleaner. Is there a way to make it work using extension methods?

Comment: I can't think of anything at the moment and haven't come across any documentation about being able to do that as yet.

Comment: You're right. Action methods cannot be used as extension methods. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514087/extend-asp-net-mvc-action-method-how-to-do-return-view) question. Please modify your answer to include that information. Also can I return more than one content type, like "image/jpg", "image/png", and so on.

Comment: The header will only include one type at a time. I would suggest mapping the file to its mime type and including that in the stream result. But that a whole other question. There are answers to that on SO.